# jQuery - turn off transition for a while

Tags: jquery, css-transitions, slide

I have a task to slide images on button click. Images have transition. If I want to show next slide, current moves left and after next slide shows it hides to the right. When I want to show previous slide, it must quickly move to the left to appear on the left side. I need to turn off transition, move slide and then turn on transition.

```js
let previous = $('#' + $(this).attr('data-slide')); // previous slide

previous.addClass('removedTransition'); // trying to move image quickly without transition
previous.addClass('movedLeft');
previous.removeClass('removedTransition');
// .visible is the current slide
$('.visible').removeClass('visible'); // hide current slide
previous.addClass('visible').removeClass('movedLeft'); // make previous one visible
```

```css
.slide {
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.slide.movedLeft {
  transform: translateX(-20%);
}

.slide.removedTransition {
  transition: 0;
}

.slide.visible {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="switch_buttons">
    <div class="button" data-slide="1"></div>
    <div class="button" data-slide="2"></div>
    <div class="button" data-slide="3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="slides">
    <img src="1.jpg" class="slide visible" id="1" />
    <img src="2.jpg" class="slide" id="2" />
    <img src="3.jpg" class="slide" id="3" />
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery seems to be ignoring 2-4 lines and shows previous slide from the right (where it was). How can I move slide to the left quickly without transition?

Comment: This code just shows various classes being added and removed from an element, but no actual styles or behaviour. Can you show us the CSS or JS where the actual transitions are defined? (Click [edit] under the question, don't try to post it as a comment.)

Comment: Sure, added CSS

Comment: adding the whole html css js would be great !